# why's my parallax scroll not working?

Tags: html, css

I want to make parallax scroll but it seems like background-attachment isn't working at all for me.
What should I do to make the blue background fixed and let the second div to scroll over it?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
}

#mainpage {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #83b2d9;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}

#subpage {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>trrtr</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="mainpage">
</div>
<div id="subpage">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur, sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed;` works with image not color

Comment: I also tried using image but it didn't work either for me...:(

Answer (score 0):

By making the **MainPage** div `position:fixed;`, you can make that div to stay at the screen forever......

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
}

#mainpage {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #83b2d9;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}

#subpage {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>trrtr</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="mainpage">
</div>
<div id="subpage">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur, sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>trrtr</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="mainpage" >
     <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="subpage">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur, sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>


 @charset "UTF-8";

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #mainpage {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg');
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #subpage {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

and here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1x7m9en/)